# 'Ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 186: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode

```
for key, value in supportProjectDict.iteritems():
        line = re.sub(r'%s,' % key, r'%s,' % value, line.decode('utf-8'), flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Trying to do a regex substitution by replacing any found keys of a dictionary with their corresponding values, but get this error once it runs into a non-ASCII character:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 186: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Shouldn't the usage of the re.UNICODE flag be preventing this?

Comment: Try `line = re.sub(ur'%s,' % key.decode('utf8'), ur'%s,' % value.decode('utf8'), line.decode('utf-8'), flags=re.UNICODE).encode("utf8")`. The point is that you need to use convert everything to Unicode. I guess it is Python 2, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using python 2.7. Although I am still getting error with your changes

Comment: Please post the contents of your values, especially `key` and `value`. What encoding do you use?

Comment: If `line` is already Unicode, that error will occur.  Check `type(line)` and possibly remove `.decode('utf8')`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.decode('utf8')` every time you use a variable, and `.encode("utf8")` the result and all the strings should be passed as Unicode strings:

```
line = re.sub(ur'%s,' % key.decode('utf8'), ur'%s,' % value.decode('utf8'), line.decode('utf8'), flags=re.UNICODE).encode("utf8")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9ndU2c)

Comment: I am still getting these errors unfortunately. The keys and values are all 100% ascii/alphanumeric characters I think it runs into this when running over text that I want to leave alone

Comment: If the `key` and `value` are ASCII, you [can use `line = re.sub(ur'%s,' % key, ur'%s,' % value, line.decode('utf-8'), flags=re.UNICODE).encode("utf8")`](http://ideone.com/D7dpJn). If it does not work, please provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This works.  I used clearly non-ASCII strings for testing:

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
import re

supportProjectDict = {u'名字':u'马克'} # Note Unicode strings
line = '名字, 有空吗？'                # Note NOT Unicode string.
for key, value in supportProjectDict.iteritems():
        line = re.sub(r'%s,' % key, r'%s,' % value, line.decode('utf-8'), flags=re.UNICODE)
print line
```

It's better to use Unicode everywhere:

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
import re

supportProjectDict = {u'名字':u'马克'}
line = u'名字, 有空吗？'
for key, value in supportProjectDict.iteritems():
        line = re.sub(ur'%s,' % key, ur'%s,' % value, line, flags=re.UNICODE)
print line
```

The format strings don't really matter in this instance because they are ASCII and Python 2 will `.decode('ascii')` implicitly to convert to Unicode strings, but it is best to be explicit.  FYI, Python 3 doesn't do implicit encode/decode so it is easier to catch these errors.